# Get type of content inside string

Tags: javascript, string, typeof

I have a situation where I get user input (completely uncontrolled) and I need to get the type of the content inside the string. For example `"[]"` and `"{}"` would be Object, `"123"` would be number, and `"'Hello'"` would be a string.

I have tried

```
new Function([], 'return typeof ' + myString)
```

but this also allows someone to run Javascript

```
(var input = 'alert()'; var x = new Function([], 'return typeof ' + input); console.log(x());).eval
```

is even worse because it runs in the same scope which gives it access to local variables. Is there an easier way to do this, or will I have to write my own program to parse the string? If there is, what is it?

Comment: Have you tried `JSON.parse`?

Comment: With the exception of your string, `typeof JSON.parse(str)` would do what you want. Now, if your string were to use double-quotes, ie `'"Hello"'`, that would also work

Comment: Thank you for the help. I didn't think of this.